# Typescript error using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, styled-components, tsx

Having the following:

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "lib": ["es2015","dom"]
    }
}
```

> Note declaration : true

And **.tsx** file:

```
import * as styledComponents from "styled-components";

export const backColor = (props: MyProps) => props.theme.backColor;

export const Title = styledComponents.div`  
   text-align: center;
   background-color:${backColor};
   width: 100%;
`;
```

When I run `tsc` on the terminal to compile I get:

> error TS2339: Property 'div' does not exist on type 'typeof "/root/node_modules/styled-comp...'.

**UPDATE**

The error happens with both ways of importing styled-components

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import * as styled from 'styled-components'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`declaration` in tsconfig is only telling it to generate type defs for your own files in the build output, not specifying how to import them from others

As they are not exporting a namespace in their type defs, but the interface itself, your import just needs to be changed to:

```
import styledComponents from "styled-components";
```

EDIT

On further investigation, the above works with `declarations` turned off or when not exporting the component

However it fails when `declarations` is true AND exporting the component, as it tries to generate your own type defs using their external interface `StyledComponentClass` that is not in scope.
`[ts] Exported variable 'Title' has or is using name 'StyledComponentClass' from external module "/blah/blah/node_modules/styled-components/typings/styled-components" but cannot be named.`

To fix it you must also explicitly import the class type definition along with the default:

```
import styledComponents, { StyledComponentClass } from 'styled-components';

export const backColor = (props: MyProps) => props.theme.backColor;

export const Title = styledComponents.div`  
   text-align: center;
   background-color:${backColor};
   width: 100%;
`;
```

Comment: Tks for your time. I know the `declaration`'s meaning. But if I put declaration=false the error is avoided. It is only when declaration=true that I get this error. I do need the declarations because I am building a React Component Library...

Comment: Ah yep, have recreated with declarations true and exporting the component - updated answer should fix it

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this error when I used VSCode to rename a div to Div (which was what I named my styled component).

I suspected my rename might have taken effect in some styled-components / React core files and the changes wouldn't show on git tracking since those are git ignored files. Hence, easily missed.

The solution for me was to `delete node_modules/` and do `npm install` again.

Comment: faced same issue, was about to delete my vite project setup and move back to CRA, Thankyou it helped.  

Answer (score 2):

Bit late, But installing styled-components' types worked for me.

`npm i @types/styled-components`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way without importing anything besides styled from "styled-components" is this:

```
    const StyledComponent = styled.div`
        background: black;
        color: white;
    `;

    const StyledComponentWithParams = styled.div<{ color?: string }>`
        background: yellow;
        color: ${(color) => (color ? "yellow" : "white")};
    `;

    const StyledComponentDefaultValueParams = styled.div<{ color?: string }>`
        background: yellow;
        color: ${(color = "white") => (color)};
    `;
```

The `StyledComponent` contains no parameters.

The `StyledComponentWithParams` and `StyledComponentDefaultValueParams` both contain a parameter but the latter sets the parameter, `color`'s default value in the arrow function's parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was corrupted type files in node_modules. Fixed with

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

By importing it with require I got to avoid the error:

```
const styledComponents = require('styled-components');
```

Comment: Thats because by using `require` you lose all type checking from that point, it automatically becomes `any`

Comment: Ouch! True... That is the only work around that worked for me so far. tks for the clarification!